# Cómo hacer una interpolacion en una matriz en python

Tags: python, numpy

Hola cómo dice el titulo quiero hacer una interpolacion tengo una matriz de (3,9) con unos valores, quiero llevarla a una matriz de (30,90) los valores iniciales son lecturas de rssi(decibeles entre -20 y -80) la verdad llevo dos días tratando de encontrar una solución pero aún no doy con ella, espero me ayuden.

Este es mi codigo:

```
import numpy as np


suma2 = np.array([[-67.15384615, -58.,         -70.5       ],
                 [-62.41666667, -55.75,       -67.92307692],
                 [-51.83333333, -62.76923077, -69.        ]])
suma3 = np.array([[-73.92307692, -63.58333333, -72.91666667],
                 [-59.91666667, -71.66666667, -56.38461538],
                 [-73.41666667, -63.07692308, -29.69230769]])
suma1 = np.array([[-44.61538462, -52.5,        -65.08333333],
                 [-66.41666667, -66.91666667, -65.30769231],
                 [-64.66666667, -58.76923077, -66.07692308]])
matriz = np.concatenate((suma2,suma3,suma1),axis=1)
mapa = np.zeros((30,60))
difh = np.zeros((3,6))
difv = np.zeros((2,9))
muestras = 10
col,w ,r, jj,count = 0,0,0,0,0


for i in range(3):
    for j in range(6):
        if j == 2:
            jj+=1
        elif j == 4:
            jj+=1
        difh[i][j] = matriz[i][j+1+jj]-matriz[i][j+jj]
    jj=0    
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(9):
        difv[i][j] = matriz[i+1][j]-matriz[i][j]     


print(difh)
for k in range(1):

    for j in range(60):

        if col == 1:
            if  r == 2 :
                    jj+=1
            elif r == 4:
                    jj+=1

        if col == 0 :

            if count == 0 :
                mapa[k][j] = matriz[w][r+jj+1]
            else:
                mapa[k][j] = matriz[w][r+jj]
            col+=1

        elif col > 0:
            mapa[k][j] = matriz[w][r+jj] + col*difh[w][r]/(muestras-1)
            col+=1

        if col == muestras:
            col = 0

            count +=1

            if r == 5:
                r = 0 
            else:
                r+=1


    w+=1
    jj=0
    count=0
    if w == 3:
        w=0

print(mapa[0:1][0:19])
```

Edit:

un ejemplo de lo que quiero es lo siguiente, sí tengo esta matriz:

```
[[1 2 3]
 [3 4 5]
 [8 9 0]]
```

El resultado debería ser algo así:(¿una especie de mapa de calor? la verdad no sé cómo llamarlo)

```
[[1   1.1 1.2 ... 1.9  2  2.1 2.2 ... 2.9  3 ]
 [1.2 1.3 1.4 ... 2.1 2.2 2.3 2.4 ... 3.1 3.2]
 [1.4 1.5 1.6 ... 2.3 2.4 2.5 2.6 ... 3.3 3.4]
 [... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...]
 [2.8 2.9 3.0 ... 3.8 3.9 4.0 4.1 ... 4.8 4.9]
 [ 3  3.1 3.2 ... 3.9  4  4.1 4.2 ... 4.9  5 ]
 [3.4 3.5 3.6 ... 4.3 4.4 4.5 4.6 ... 5.3 5.4]
 [3.8 3.9 4.0 ... 4.7 4.8 4.9 5.0 ... 5.7 5.8]
 [... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...]
 [6.6 6.7 6.8 ... 7.5 7.6 7.7 7.8 ... 8.5 8.6]
 [ 7  7.1 7.2 ... 7.9  8  8.1 8.2 ... 8.9  9 ]
```

de otra forma, lo explicaré así, un linspace de tamaño 10 desde [(0,0) a (0,1)] otro de [(0,0) a (1,0)] otro de [(0,1) a (0,2)] otro de  [(0,1) a (1,1)] y así, lo que no me queda claro es despues de formar esta matriz:

```
[[+ + + + + + + + + + + + + + +]
 [+             +             +]
 [+             +             +]
 [+             +             +]
 [+             +             +]
 [+ + + + + + + + + + + + + + +]
 [+             +             +]
 [+             +             +]
 [+             +             +]
 [+             +             +]
 [+ + + + + + + + + + + + + + +]]
```

cómo debería proseguir, espero que haya quedado un poco más claro lo que necesito
Gracias

Comment: ¿Podrías dar un ejemplo sobre como debería ser el resultado? Quizás con una matriz de menor tamaño.

Comment: @RodrigoN ya agregue un ejemplo, espero me puedas ayudar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolviendo el ejemplo simplificado (pues el otro que pones con código no lo he entendido), supongamos que quiero "extender" el array:

```
m = np.array([[1,2,3],
              [2,5,6],
              [3,8,9]])
```

(fíjate que para la primera columna he usado  1,2,3 en vez de 1,4,7, para verlo mejor)

Se me ha ocurrido lo siguiente:

1) Crear un array lleno de ceros del tamaño apropiado. Para un "factor de escala" por así decir de 10, el tamaño final de cada fila no sería 30, como decías en la pregunta, sino 21 (pues, por ejemplo en la primera fila, serían 10 elementos entre 1 y 2, otros 10 entre 2 y 3, y finalmente el 3)

La salida de este paso sería:

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

2) Rellenar sólo algunas filas de ese array de ceros. En concreto las filas múltiplo de 10, tomando los datos del array de entrada y colocándolos en las posiciones múltiplo de 10, e interpolando (mediante `linspace()` para completar esas filas.

La salida de este paso sería:

```
[[1.  1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 1.7 1.8 1.9 2.  2.1 2.2 2.3 2.4 2.5 2.6 2.7 2.8 2.9 3. ]
 [0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]
 [0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]
 [0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]
 [0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]
 [0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]
 [0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]
 [0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]
 [0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]
 [0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]
 [2.  2.3 2.6 2.9 3.2 3.5 3.8 4.1 4.4 4.7 5.  5.1 5.2 5.3 5.4 5.5 5.6 5.7 5.8 5.9 6. ]
 [0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]
 [0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]
 [0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]
 [0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]
 [0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]
 [0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]
 [0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]
 [0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]
 [0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]
 [3.  3.5 4.  4.5 5.  5.5 6.  6.5 7.  7.5 8.  8.1 8.2 8.3 8.4 8.5 8.6 8.7 8.8 8.9 9. ]]
```

3) Para cada columna del resultado anterior, rellenar los ceros con los valores interpolados entre los elementos no-cero. El resultado de este tercer paso sería:

```
[[1.   1.1  1.2  1.3  1.4  1.5  1.6  1.7  1.8  1.9  2.   2.1  2.2  2.3  2.4  2.5  2.6  2.7  2.8  2.9  3.  ]
 [1.1  1.22 1.34 1.46 1.58 1.7  1.82 1.94 2.06 2.18 2.3  2.4  2.5  2.6  2.7  2.8  2.9  3.   3.1  3.2  3.3 ]
 [1.2  1.34 1.48 1.62 1.76 1.9  2.04 2.18 2.32 2.46 2.6  2.7  2.8  2.9  3.   3.1  3.2  3.3  3.4  3.5  3.6 ]
 [1.3  1.46 1.62 1.78 1.94 2.1  2.26 2.42 2.58 2.74 2.9  3.   3.1  3.2  3.3  3.4  3.5  3.6  3.7  3.8  3.9 ]
 [1.4  1.58 1.76 1.94 2.12 2.3  2.48 2.66 2.84 3.02 3.2  3.3  3.4  3.5  3.6  3.7  3.8  3.9  4.   4.1  4.2 ]
 [1.5  1.7  1.9  2.1  2.3  2.5  2.7  2.9  3.1  3.3  3.5  3.6  3.7  3.8  3.9  4.   4.1  4.2  4.3  4.4  4.5 ]
 [1.6  1.82 2.04 2.26 2.48 2.7  2.92 3.14 3.36 3.58 3.8  3.9  4.   4.1  4.2  4.3  4.4  4.5  4.6  4.7  4.8 ]
 [1.7  1.94 2.18 2.42 2.66 2.9  3.14 3.38 3.62 3.86 4.1  4.2  4.3  4.4  4.5  4.6  4.7  4.8  4.9  5.   5.1 ]
 [1.8  2.06 2.32 2.58 2.84 3.1  3.36 3.62 3.88 4.14 4.4  4.5  4.6  4.7  4.8  4.9  5.   5.1  5.2  5.3  5.4 ]
 [1.9  2.18 2.46 2.74 3.02 3.3  3.58 3.86 4.14 4.42 4.7  4.8  4.9  5.   5.1  5.2  5.3  5.4  5.5  5.6  5.7 ]
 [2.   2.3  2.6  2.9  3.2  3.5  3.8  4.1  4.4  4.7  5.   5.1  5.2  5.3  5.4  5.5  5.6  5.7  5.8  5.9  6.  ]
 [2.1  2.42 2.74 3.06 3.38 3.7  4.02 4.34 4.66 4.98 5.3  5.4  5.5  5.6  5.7  5.8  5.9  6.   6.1  6.2  6.3 ]
 [2.2  2.54 2.88 3.22 3.56 3.9  4.24 4.58 4.92 5.26 5.6  5.7  5.8  5.9  6.   6.1  6.2  6.3  6.4  6.5  6.6 ]
 [2.3  2.66 3.02 3.38 3.74 4.1  4.46 4.82 5.18 5.54 5.9  6.   6.1  6.2  6.3  6.4  6.5  6.6  6.7  6.8  6.9 ]
 [2.4  2.78 3.16 3.54 3.92 4.3  4.68 5.06 5.44 5.82 6.2  6.3  6.4  6.5  6.6  6.7  6.8  6.9  7.   7.1  7.2 ]
 [2.5  2.9  3.3  3.7  4.1  4.5  4.9  5.3  5.7  6.1  6.5  6.6  6.7  6.8  6.9  7.   7.1  7.2  7.3  7.4  7.5 ]
 [2.6  3.02 3.44 3.86 4.28 4.7  5.12 5.54 5.96 6.38 6.8  6.9  7.   7.1  7.2  7.3  7.4  7.5  7.6  7.7  7.8 ]
 [2.7  3.14 3.58 4.02 4.46 4.9  5.34 5.78 6.22 6.66 7.1  7.2  7.3  7.4  7.5  7.6  7.7  7.8  7.9  8.   8.1 ]
 [2.8  3.26 3.72 4.18 4.64 5.1  5.56 6.02 6.48 6.94 7.4  7.5  7.6  7.7  7.8  7.9  8.   8.1  8.2  8.3  8.4 ]
 [2.9  3.38 3.86 4.34 4.82 5.3  5.78 6.26 6.74 7.22 7.7  7.8  7.9  8.   8.1  8.2  8.3  8.4  8.5  8.6  8.7 ]
 [3.   3.5  4.   4.5  5.   5.5  6.   6.5  7.   7.5  8.   8.1  8.2  8.3  8.4  8.5  8.6  8.7  8.8  8.9  9.  ]]
```

La siguiente función hace todo esto para la matriz `m` que le pases como parámetro, y el "factor de escala" que quieras (10 por defecto):

```
import numpy as np

def scalematrix(m, scale=10):
  # Crear matriz con ceros del tamaño apropiado
  r = np.zeros(((m.shape[0]-1)*scale+1, (m.shape[1]-1)*scale+1))

  # Rellenar filas multiplo de scale (interpolando entre valores de los elementos de la fila)
  for fil in range(m.shape[0]):
    for col in range(m.shape[1]-1):
      r[fil*scale, col*scale:(col+1)*scale+1] = np.linspace(m[fil,col], m[fil,col+1], scale+1)

  # Rellenar resto de ceros, interpolando entre elementos de las columnas
  for fil in range(m.shape[0]-1):
    for col in range(r.shape[1]):
      r[fil*scale:(fil+1)*scale + 1, col] = np.linspace(r[fil*scale,col], r[(fil+1)*scale, col], scale+1)
  return r
```

Otro ejemplo:

```
m = np.array([[1,2,3],
              [4,9,6]])

np.set_printoptions(precision=3, linewidth=200)
print(scalematrix(m, 5))
```

```
[[1.   1.2  1.4  1.6  1.8  2.   2.2  2.4  2.6  2.8  3.  ]
 [1.6  1.96 2.32 2.68 3.04 3.4  3.44 3.48 3.52 3.56 3.6 ]
 [2.2  2.72 3.24 3.76 4.28 4.8  4.68 4.56 4.44 4.32 4.2 ]
 [2.8  3.48 4.16 4.84 5.52 6.2  5.92 5.64 5.36 5.08 4.8 ]
 [3.4  4.24 5.08 5.92 6.76 7.6  7.16 6.72 6.28 5.84 5.4 ]
 [4.   5.   6.   7.   8.   9.   8.4  7.8  7.2  6.6  6.  ]]
```

La representación gráfica de la matriz de entrada y la de salida serían las siguientes (obtenidas con `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow()`):

[image: Entrada] [image: Salida]

Comment: Gracias! eso era lo que necesitaba :)